# Lodash merge two arrays with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have 2 arrays like below:

```
const array1 = [{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "4"}];
const array2 = [{name: "1"}, {name: "5"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "1"}, {name: "1"}, {name: "2"}];
```

Expected Output is:

```
[{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "5"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "1"}, {name: "1"}];
```

The result array should contain the array1's all elements
and those elements from array2 that are not already present in array1

I tried using `_.unionBy`

```
_.unionBy(array1, array2, 'name')
```

but it only results an array with uniq 'name'

How can we achieve that using lodash?

Comment: "The result array should contain the array1's all elements and those elements from array2 that are not already present in array1's sequence" and the expected output is not matched together.

Comment: The _"expected Output"_ in your question does not match the description of the _"expected output"_ - Why are there `name: 1` and `name: 2` elements at the end?

Comment: i think he wants all from array1 and the ones in array2 when element is different for same index

Comment: @Andreas array1 contains `{name: "1"}` and array2 contains `{name: "1"}` and as this is present in array1's element sequence we discard it. array2 has {name: "1"}, {name: "1"}, {name: "2"} that are not present in array1's element sequence (as we already have discarded matched {name: "1"}) 

I will describe more in detail

Comment: why do you have `{ name: "2" }` at last item?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry for the confusion. Yes you are right,  { name: "2" } should not be present in result array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unionBy` (lodash)

```
let result = _.unionBy(array1 , array2, 'name');
```

**unionBy** - https://docs-lodash.com/v4/union-by/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want `{ name: "2" }` as last item of the result set, you could count the grouped items and add wanted items.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "2" }, { name: "3" }, { name: "4" }, { name: "4" }],
    array2 = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "5" }, { name: "3" }, { name: "4" }, { name: "4"}, { name: "4" }, { name: "1" }, { name: "1" }, { name: "2" }],
    counts = {},
    result = array1.map(o => (counts[o.name] = (counts[o.name] || 0) + 1, o));

result.push(...array2.filter(o => !counts[o.name] || !counts[o.name]--));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```